# Invertibility of the rotation map

Tags: dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

The rotation of the circle by a real number $\lambda$ is the function $f_\lambda:S^1 \to S^1$ defined by
\begin{align}
f_\lambda(x)=x+\lambda,\quad \text{mod}\,\mathbb{Z}
\end{align}
We know that if $\lambda$ is a rational number, then every point of $S^1$ is periodic and if $\lambda$ is irrational then $\text{Per(f)}=\emptyset$ and the orbit of every point in $S^1$ is dense in the whole space ($S^1$).

My question is about invertibility of this function. I think in the case the points rotated by the rational parameter the answer is positive, but I'm not sure about the "Irrational Rotation" ?

Comment: In both cases, it is invertible and the inverse is $x \mapsto x-\lambda$

Comment: @Albert Thank you for your answer. What if we partition the space $S^1$ into subsegments $M_j$ and then rotate each point of $M_j$ by a special $\lambda_j$ ?Could we say in both cases they are invertible yet?

Comment: not in general. If that is the case that interests you, you should modify your question accordingly